# What is the correct type of Exception to throw in a Nestjs service?

Tags: exception, filter, scope, nestjs

So, by reading the NestJS documentation, I get the main idea behind how the filters work with exceptions.

But from all the code I have seen, it seems like all services always throw HttpExceptions.

My question is: **Should the services really be throwing HttpExceptions**? I mean, shouldn't they be more generic? And, if so, what kind of Error/Exception should I throw and how should I implement the filter to catch it, so I won't need to change it later when my service is not invoked by a Http controller?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they should not. An `HttpException` should be thrown from within a controller. So yes, your services should expose their own errors in a more generic way.
But "exposing errors" doesn't have to mean "throwing exceptions".

Let's say you have the following project structure :

```
 sample
 |_  sample.controller.ts
 |_  sample.service.ts
```

When calling one of your `SampleService` methods, you want your `SampleController` to know whether or not it should throw an `HttpException`.

This is where your `SampleService` comes into play. It is not going to throw anything but it's rather going to return a specific object that will tell your controller what to do.

Consider the two following classes :

```js
export class Error {
  constructor(
    readonly code: number,
    readonly message: string,
  ) {}
}

export class Result<T> {
  constructor(readonly data: T) {}
}
```

Now take a look at this random `SampleService` class and how it makes use of them :

```js
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {

  isOddCheck(numberToCheck: number): Error | Result<boolean> {
    const isOdd = numberToCheck%2 === 0;
    if (isOdd) {
      return new Result(isOdd);
    }

    return new Error(
      400,
      `Number ${numberToCheck} is even.`
    );
  }

}
```

Finally this is how your `SampleController` should look like :

```js
@Controller()
export class SampleController {
  constructor(
    private readonly sampleService: SampleService
  ) {}

  @Get()
  sampleGetResponse(): boolean {
    const result = this.sampleService.isOddCheck(13);
    if (result instanceof Result) {
      return result.data;
    }
    
    throw new HttpException(
      result.message,
      result.code,
    );
  }

}
```

As you can see nothing gets thrown from your service. It only exposes whether or not an error has occurred. Only your controller gets the responsibility to throw an `HttpException` when it needs to.

Also notice that I didn't use any exception filter. I didn't have to. But I hope this helps.